# SQL - referential integrity - Foreign key and Check constraint

Tags: referential-integrity

Please let me know if below two declarations are same.

```
create table R1
( a INT PRIMARY KEY, 
  b INT references K(w));
```

Note: K is a table with single attribute w as primary key

```
create table R1
( a INT PRIMARY KEY, 
  b INT CHECK (b in (SELECT w FROM K));
```

Comment: If `K(w)` is a primary or unique key, they are similar declarations. But most SQL products accept only the first syntax (`FOREIGN KEY` constraint) and not the second (which has a subquery in a `CHECK` constraint)

Comment: Not all DBMSes allow subselects in check constraints.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question of whether they are equivalent, you need to declare K. Assuming:

```
create table K (x int not null primary key, w int, unique(w));
insert into K (x) values (1);
insert into K (x) values (2);
```

The following would satisfy the CHECK constraint:

```
insert into R1 (a,b) values (1,1);
```

because:

```
CHECK (b in (SELECT w FROM K))
```

evaluates to:

```
CHECK (b in (null, null)) <=> CHECK (null)
```

The rule is that the constraint must not evaluate to false. I don't know any DBMS that support subqueries in CHECK constraints, so I can't verify that.

I tested the foreign key variant against PostgreSQL 11, and the insert is rejected

```
 ERROR:  insert or update on table "r1" violates foreign key constraint "r1_b_fkey" DETAIL:  Key (b)=(1) is not present in table "k".
```